# Entity Framework 6 Free Oracle Data Provider

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

Do you know if there out there a free Oracle Data Provider for entity framework 6?
I could only get the Devart one, but it has a paid license.

I need this, since we are working with an Oracle db with boolean properties map as char(1) and EF5 does not support this kind of feature.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this one not work? [Oracle Database 12c Release 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-win64-download-1968077.html)

Comment: Hi @JayWalker
Thanks for the quick response. That, won't work since EF6 has changed and now you get the following exception if you use the Oracle provider: The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' did not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'. 
Entity Framework providers must extend from this class and the 'Instance' member must return the Singleton instance of the provider.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there currently there an Oracle provider for EF6 from Oracle but DevArt has shipped an EF6 compliant provider. See [this blog post](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html) for more details. Make sure to download the latest version (the post is dated a bit). I [tried](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/04/14/entity-framework-6-on-mono/) their EF6 provider for MySQL and it worked so I assume the Oracle one will work too.

Comment: Thank @Pawel, I have tried with the free version of the Oracle provider, unfortunately, it does not support EF, just ADO.NET as you can see [link](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/editions.html)