# Visual Studio 2013 ADO.net entity model does not have Oracle data source

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I've just installed visual studio 2013 and tried to setup Entity framework to access an oracle database.

I click on new ADO.NET entity model, then Generate from database, but on the data connection screen when I click "New Connection" I don't get oracle appearing the list of datasources. I only get two SQL server options.

Do I need to install something extra to get this to work?

The Oracle data source appears in my 2012 version of visual studio that I've got installed on the same machine, so not sure why it doesn't work in 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it has not been released yet

https://forums.oracle.com/message/11239147#11239147

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Entity Framework 6 and in its first release it only has a provider for SqlServer stuff, there is a support from external tools (DevArt) have a look at this page:

[Entity Framework 6 Free Oracle Data Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684025/entity-framework-6-free-oracle-data-provider)

Comment: I checked the references on the project and I think that it's EF5, Runtime Version v4.0.30319 version 4.4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

As of Version 12.1 Release 2 Visual Studio 2013 is supported:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/newfeatures-084113.html

The Oracle provider is not yet currently built against EF6 so if you are planning on using Entity Framework in MVC5, you need to install EF5 by running "Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0" on the Package Manager Console.

If you are starting a bootstrapped MVC5 WebApp don't use the Individual User Account membership provider as it relies on EF6. You can go for one of the many alternate membership providers (http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/membership)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is way more complicated that you would expect.

1. Go here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html and download the appropriate installation file. (You have to create an Oracle account. You can choose a specific version of Visual Studio, or the 300+ MB download will handle multiple versions.)
2. Extract the zip file and run setup.exe. (I kept all the defaults.)
3. Click the Install button. (Close Visual Studio, by the way) After several minutes, it will finish installing.
4. Open Visual Studio, create new ADO.NET entity model, Generate from database, New Connection. This time hopefully you will as your Data Source: *Oracle Database (ODP.NET, Managed Driver)*.